# VB - Calling Sub doesn't work from all classes

Tags: vb.net, forms, call, subroutine

I have a sub (Named "StartStop") that is called from a couple different buttons as well as from another form. All of the forms are their default instance and the sub is called the same way each time:

The Buttons on the "Main" Form:

```
Call StartStop(Start.Text, "Server")

Call StartStop(Weekend.Text, "Server")
```

From the problem Form:

```
           Select Case MessageParse(2)
                Case "Start"
                    Call Main.StartStop("Start", MessageParse(1))
                Case "Stop"
                    Call Main.StartStop("Pause", MessageParse(1))
                Case "Weekend"
                    Call Main.StartStop("Weekend", MessageParse(1))
                Case "Weekday"
                    Call Main.StartStop("Weekday", MessageParse(1))
```

My issue is that from my problem form, (named "CommServer"), it calls the sub and runs through the code but does not execute any of it. I can step through it and watch it run line by line without any apparent change.

If I call it the same way from a third unrelated form, for the sake of testing, everything works the same way it does from the buttons which is leading me to believe it's something with my CommServer form. Here's a snippet from the called Sub:

```
Public Sub StartStop(ByVal Action As String, ByVal User As String)

    Select Case Action
        Case "Start"
            Countdown.Interval = 500
            TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeLimit)
            Countdown.Start()
            GameUpdateTimer.Interval = GameSpeed * 1000
            GameUpdateTimer.Start()
            Start.Text = "Pause"
            Weekend.Enabled = True
            GameOn = True
            CommServer.xUpdate("StartStop" & "`" & "Start", True)
            CommServer.xUpdate("ChatMessage" & "`" & User & " Started The Game", True)
```

I can step through the sub, and even watch it loop back to the CommServer form and run through the xUpdate Sub over there, except nothing happens. However if I dropped the line `MsgBox("Test")` in that code it would produce a message box but ignore everything else.

So my question is, what should I be looking for in my CommServer form that would pass by the code without executing it? I've scoured my code and can't find any evidence that these forms are not the default instance.

Thanks in Advance, I hope it's easy!

Comment: Whats MessageParse, from the looks of it your not doing anything with it?

Comment: Is that second code snippet being executed on a secondary thread by any chance?

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR MessageParse seems to be adding the user in the last line with "xUpdate"

Comment: The CommServer is a form that receives text commands with information separated by the ` character. It parses into the MessageParse array, evaluates it and decides what to do with it. When I watch it while debugging, the information passed into the Byvals is functioning as designed. To answer jmcilhinney's question, I would say that the CommServer is operating in a different thread... at least, part of it is. I have very little experience with threads and I followed a tutorial for the network portion of this program. How would I communicate between threads if this was the issue?